# NSPredicate Password Format

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I'm trying to figure out an accurate solution for validating a password field using `NSPredicate`. Here's my code:

```
-(int)checkPasswordStrength:(NSString *)password
{
    NSPredicate *validPassword = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",@"\\b^(?=.*[0-9]+?)(?=.*[A-Z]+?)(?=.*[a-z]*?)(?=.*[!@#$%?]+?)[0-9A-z!@#$%?]{8,20}$\\b"];
    NSString *escapedPassword = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:password];
    if(![validPassword evaluateWithObject:escapedPassword]) {
        [Helper showAlertWithTitle:@"" Message:@"Password should contain 8 to 20 alphanumeric characters, one capitalized letter, and with at least one of the symbols (e.g. !@#$%?)"];
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I've tried the patterns:

```
\\b^(?=.*[0-9]+?)(?=(.*\\d){1})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%?]).*[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%?]{8,20}\\b

\\b^(?=.*[0-9]+?)(?=.*[A-Z]+?)(?=.*[a-z]*?)(?=.*[!@#$%?]+?)[0-9A-z!@#$%?]{8,20}$\\b

\\b^(?=.*[0-9]+?)(?=.*[A-Z]+?)(?=.*[a-z]*?)(?=.*[!@#$%?]+?)[0-9A-z!@#$%?]{8,20}$\\b
```

... Both **without escaping** and **escaping** the strings, but it would not just work for this type of password patterns (wherein the special characters are found after the **first** and **last** password string):

```
OverAndUnder21!
AreYouHere2?
PleaseDial9#
!4Ngrier!
!D4ngerZone
```

All the other passwords work:

```
P@MyF8fulDog
classM8s4L!fe
```

And so on...

I tried to test my RegEx patterns in regex101.com, and it seems to have a full match.

What is the right validation pattern in `NSPredicate` to allow the **special characters as the first and last characters**?

Comment: Your consuming part does not allow `?`. Try adding it and removing word boundaries: `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%?])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%?]{8,20}$`

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I've added the question mark in the question and in my code, but it still does not accept the last character as a special character to validate the passwords.

Comment: Did you remove word boundaries? See https://regex101.com/r/Y1d0u6/1

Comment: Yes, I did remove it. It works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove word boundaries and add a question mark to the pattern:

```
@"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%?])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%?]{8,20}$"
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Y1d0u6/1).

The word boundary at the start and end of the pattern requires the first and last char to be a word char (a letter, digit or `_`).

Also, note `+?` is not necessary inside lookaheads as you just require at least 1 instance of the patterns.